# Pushing objects into an array of objects duplicates the already existing objects in that array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, local-storage, push

Like the question says,  when I push objects into an array of objects it duplicates the already existing objects in that array. Only after page reload the copies are removed. I know it has got to do with reference. I tried copying the object that is pushed into the array, created a new object with props all to no effect. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
// The persons array is an array of objects 
import { persons } from './main.js';

let entriesFound = []
let data = localStorage.getItem('entriesFound') ;

if(data){
    entriesFound = JSON.parse(data)
    loadList(entriesFound)
}

//Renders the search results to the UI from localStorage
function loadList(array) {

    for(let el of array) {
        const html = 
        `<div id="${el.id}" class="item2">
        <div class="info2">Name:<div class="name">${el.name}</div></div>
        <div class="info2">Date of birth:<div class="born">${el.dob}</div></div>
        <div class="info2">Age:<div class="age">${el.age}</div></div>
        <div class="info2">Place of birth:<div class="city">${el.city}</div></div>
        <div class="info2">ID:<div class="id">${el.id}</div></div>
        <div class="info2">Entered:<div class="added">${el.entered}</div></div>
        </div>`;

     document.querySelector('.searchResult').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html)
    }
}

//Search button to search for entry (in the persons array) that matches the condtional 
export const searchBtn = document.querySelector('.search').addEventListener('click' , function() {

    // Get search string from search bar
    const name = document.querySelector('.searchInput')

   // persons array
     persons.filter( el => {
        if(el.name === name.value) {
           entriesFound.push(el);   // Pushes the object (el) to the entriesFound array
        }                           // I guess this is were it goes wrong
    })
        addItem(entriesFound)
        name.value = ""
        localStorage.setItem('entriesFound', JSON.stringify(entriesFound))
})

// Renders the new search result to the UI
function addItem(entries) {
    for( let item of entries) {
        const html = 
                `<div id="${item.id}" class="item2">
                <div class="info2">Name:<div class="name">${item.name}</div></div>
                <div class="info2">Date of birth:<div class="born">${item.dob}</div></div>
                <div class="info2">Age:<div class="age">${item.age}</div></div>
                <div class="info2">Place of birth:<div class="city">${item.city}</div></div>
                <div class="info2">ID:<div class="id">${item.id}</div></div>
                <div class="info2">Entered:<div class="added">${item.entered}</div></div>
                </div>`;
    
             document.querySelector('.searchResult').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html)
        }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `persons.filter()` use `persons.forEach()`. The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented and it is not needed in this case.

Comment: Yes, I know, I did exactly that, but that didn't solve my problem at that stage. Thanks anyway for checking.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The addItem function loops over the entire entriesFound array, while it only has to add one entry to the search results.

```
     persons.forEach( el => {
        if(el.name === name.value) {
           addItem(el)                 <---- like so, el is an object from 
                                             the persons array of objects!
           entriesFound.push(el);   
        }                           
    })
        addItem(entriesFound)
        name.value = ""
        localStorage.setItem('entriesFound', JSON.stringify(entriesFound))
})

// Renders the new search result to the UI
function addItem(entry) {
                                       <--- got rid of the loop!
        const html = 
                `<div id="${entry.id}" class="item2">
                <div class="info2">Name:<div class="name">${entry.name}</div></div>
                <div class="info2">Date of birth:<div class="born">${entry.dob}</div></div>
                <div class="info2">Age:<div class="age">${entry.age}</div></div>
                <div class="info2">Place of birth:<div class="city">${entry.city}</div></div>
                <div class="info2">ID:<div class="id">${entry.id}</div></div>
                <div class="info2">Entered:<div class="added">${entry.entered}</div></div>
                </div>`;
    
             document.querySelector('.searchResult').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html)
        }
```